# Change url of posts with keywords

Tags: plugins, urls

I have a website which is using general URL of word press like

https://mywebsite.org/item/itempostname

Every category post have a location. So i want to modify general URL to custom URL like
https://mywebsite.org/alaska/itempostname

Here Alaska,Chicago etc is a location.

Add location URL : `http://mywebsite/wordpress/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=item-location&post_type=item`

[image]

Is this possible ?
Is this possible with any plugin ?
I need your help on this topic.

Comment: What is a "location"? Custom meta? Custom taxonomy? Category?

Comment: Unless I misunderstood, just go to settings > permalink and then set the URL to custom e.g. /%category%/%postname%/ and that will make the url as /category/post-name, set the category as the location

Comment: i think location is taxonomy. i have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using custom post type with custom category is it?If so, then I suggest using this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/

Set it up, go to Settings -> permalink settings and there will be an additional settings called "Permalink Settings for Custom Post types". Enter something like :

```
/%item%/%postname%
```

If you are not using a custom taxonomy, simply put `/%category%/%postname%/` in permalinks and it should work.

Update:

Try using  `/%item-location%/%postname%`

Comment: i think location is taxonomy. i have updated my question.